# How can we call sql server stored procedure using odbc_exec in php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, procedure

How can we call sql server stored procedure using odbc_exec in php.

I tried this code but it doesnt work:

```
include '../config2.php';

$sql = "EXEC MENTAL('F200', 'D', '39','41','1')";
$result=odbc_exec($baglanti, $sql);

while($query = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $html .= $query['Code'] . ' ' . $query['CodeType'] . ' ' . 
             $query['TANIM'] . ' ' . $query['VakaSayısı'] . '<br>';
}    

echo $html;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok Folks I found the solution:
Sql statemtn must be like this:

$sql = "EXEC MENTAL @code='F200' , @Statu='D'";